# Null pointer exception occurs when showing a barchart by consuming a web service using soap method in android?

Tags: android, web-services, bar-chart

Can any one tell me what this logcat is saying.Here i am trying to show a bar-chart in android by consuming a web service using SOAP method.

**Logcat**

```
09-18 19:13:52.804: D/AndroidRuntime(367): Shutting down VM
09-18 19:13:52.804: W/dalvikvm(367): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xmlparsing_test/com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity.buildBarDataset(BarGraphActivity.java:114)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity.DrawGraph(BarGraphActivity.java:56)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity.onCreate(BarGraphActivity.java:22)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  ... 11 more
```

**Chart.java**

```
public class Chart extends Activity 
{       
EditText edt1,edt2;
TextView txtv1;
Button btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    edt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
                getTMSChart(edt1.getText().toString(),edt2.getText().toString());
            Intent intnt = new Intent(v.getContext(), BarGraphActivity.class);
            startActivity(intnt);
        }
    });
 }

public void getTMSChart(String FromDate, String ToDate) 
{
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");        
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);        

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    String METHOD = "GetTMSChart";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetTMSChart"; 
    String URL = "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD); 

    request.addProperty("FromDate","");               
    request.addProperty("ToDate","");

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try 
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        SoapObject root =  (SoapObject) ((SoapObject)(result).getProperty(0)).getProperty("NewDataSet");
        int tablesCount = root.getPropertyCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < tablesCount; i++)
    {
        SoapObject table = (SoapObject) root.getProperty(i);
        int propertyCount = table.getPropertyCount();

     for (int j = 0; j < propertyCount; j++)
     {           
        //String ord = table.getPropertyAsString("");

         int orderNo = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No"));
         int freightRate =   Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate"));
         int marginPercent = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Margin_Percent"));
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) 
{}
}   }
```

**BarGraphActivity.java**

```
public class BarGraphActivity extends Chart
{   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    DrawGraph();
}

public void DrawGraph() 
{
Chart ch = new Chart();

String[] titles = new String[] { " Barcharts",""};

int[] x_axis =null;   
int[] y_axis =null;

List<int[]> values = new ArrayList<int[]>();
values.add(x_axis);
values.add(y_axis);

int[] colors = new int[] { Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK};

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
setChartSettings(renderer, "some texts", " ", " ",0,x_axis, 0,y_axis, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);

renderer.setXLabels(1);
renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "orderNo");
renderer.addYTextLabel(2, "freight");
renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);

int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
  SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
  seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
  }

ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
}

public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) 
{
    // creates a SeriesRenderer and initializes it with useful default values as well as colors

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);

int length = colors.length;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
   SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
   r.setColor(colors[i]);
   renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
  }
  return renderer;
}

 public void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String  xTitle,
 String yTitle, int xMin, int[] x_axis, int yMin, int[] y_axis, int axesColor,int labelsColor) 
{
    // sets lots of default values for this renderer

renderer.setChartTitle(title);

renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);

renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);

renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);

renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}

public XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<int[]> values) 
{
// adds the axis titles and values into the dataset

XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

int length = titles.length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
   CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);

   int[] v = values.get(i);

   int seriesLength = v.length;

   for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
   {
     series.add(v[k]);
    }

   dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
   }
 return dataset;
 } }
```

Thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: You've got a null pointer at line 114 in buildBarDataset!  What are you asking?

Comment: @Simon actually i am trying to show a barchart in android,but i want to get the x and y axis values for the bar-chart from the web service by consuming it.

Comment: @Simon but i am getting these errors on my project,can you tell me how to overcome it

Comment: If you add line numbers to your pasted source code, Simon can tell you in more detail what is going wrong.

Comment: Which line is 114?  The logcat is very clear:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 19:13:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity.buildBarDataset(BarGraphActivity.java:114)

Comment: @Simon int[] v = values.get(i);

Comment: You can't assign a null to an integer.  Since both elements of values[] are null, this will always fail.  Are you missing some code to populate x_axis and y_axis?

Comment: @Simon if i remove that null values,its expecting me to initialize the x and y-axis....But my need is, from the chart.java class i need to parse the value of orderNo and freightRate to x and y-axis values for creating a barchart

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it has something to do with this in the `DrawGraph()` method

```
int[] x_axis =null;   
int[] y_axis =null;
```

You're `.get(i)` is returning a null array.

You're adding null's to your `ArrayList<int[]>` (which I think is perfectly legal in Java, dont remember), and pulling out nulls later, and then calling `v.length`

EDIT: No...real edit to be done!

Comment: David.  I've accidentally downvoted you.  Please edit your answer so that I can restore the natural order of the Androidverse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer, only to avoid a stackoverflow in the comments list :)  I don't expect an accept.

Sorry Android_user, but you will have to significantly restructure your code.  Consider this:

```
int[] x_axis =null;   
int[] y_axis =null;

List<int[]> values = new ArrayList<int[]>();
values.add(x_axis);
values.add(y_axis);
```

At this point, you have a list of integer arrays.  This list, which is "values", has 2 elements, each of which is an uninitialised int array (x_axis and y_axis).

Later, in your buildBarDataset method, you pass in "values" as an argument.  Now consider this:

```
int[] v = values.get(i);
```

values.get(i) can only ever return null, since both of it's elements are null, and you try to assign that v.

What do you intend x_axis and y_axis to contain?  It implies to me that they are the scale values for the x and y axis, not the graph values?  Is it your intention that when buildBarDataset returns, the elements of x_axis and y_axis will contain values or that they should contain values before int[] v = values.get(i)?